# unable to return updated widget inside ValueListenableBuilder

Tags: list, flutter, widget

I need to update list inside ListView widget, so I set a valuenotifierbuilder like this:

```
final ValueNotifier<ModelRegis> modelFoto =
      ValueNotifier<ModelRegis>(ModelRegis());
```

and the structure of the model is like this

```
class ModelRegis {
  String loadFoto;
  bool adaFoto;
  int idFotoUser, index;
  List<Widget> independentFoto;
  ModelRegis(
      {this.loadFoto = "done",
      this.adaFoto = false,
      this.idFotoUser,
      this.index,
      this.independentFoto});
}
```

here is how I try to update the widget using ValueListenableBuilder

```
ValueListenableBuilder(
                                            valueListenable: modelFoto,
                                            builder: (_, val, __) {
                                              List<Widget> listFuture = [];

                                              if (val.adaFoto) {
                                                
                                                Widget dummyList =
                                                    Text("after click");
                                                List temp = val.independentFoto;
                                                temp[val.index] = dummyList;
                                                modelFoto.value = ModelRegis(
                                                    loadFoto: modelFoto
                                                        .value.loadFoto,
                                                    adaFoto:
                                                        modelFoto.value.adaFoto,
                                                    idFotoUser: modelFoto
                                                        .value.idFotoUser,
                                                    index:
                                                        modelFoto.value.index,
                                                    independentFoto: temp);
                                                // modelFoto.notifyListeners();
                                                print("2. $temp");
                                                print(
                                                    "2. ${val.independentFoto}");

                                                // modelFoto.notifyListeners();

                                                return ListView(
                                                    physics:
                                                        const AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                                                    shrinkWrap: false,
                                                    children:
                                                        val.independentFoto);
                                              }
```

I have tried to print `val.independentFoto` and the result is like this

```
[Text("after click"), FutureBuilder<dynamic>, FutureBuilder<dynamic>, FutureBuilder<dynamic>, FutureBuilder<dynamic>]
```

but the return result in ListView is always not update, so it will return a List that consist of widget like this

```
[FutureBuilder<dynamic>, FutureBuilder<dynamic>, FutureBuilder<dynamic>, FutureBuilder<dynamic>, FutureBuilder<dynamic>]
```

the return result doesn't update widget to `Text("after click")` at first index
is there a right way to update list of widget in ValueListenableBuilder?

Comment: why are you changing `modelFoto.value` inside the `builder:`? if you are not sure how to use `ValueListenableBuilder` refer to its official documentation

Comment: I need to change modelFoto.value.independentFoto, so when user click the button for second time, it should be the last list to be used

Comment: sorry i have no idea what you mean - did you check the official `ValueListenableBuilder` documentation?

Comment: I haven't check it, I read an article about it and try to implement it. I would like to make it clear that I am trying to update List inside ValueListenableBuilder but when I return the list inside ListView, the list doesn't update but when I print the List, it has been updated